# woocommerce New order transcational email

Tags: wordpress, sorting, email, woocommerce, customization

How to reorder billing address and shipping address fields order?
I want company name to be first...see the attachment.
Thanks in advance!
[image]

I managed to change order in woocommerce pages using functions.php code:

```
function woosuite_reorder_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
  $fields['company']['priority'] = 1;

  return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'woosuite_reorder_checkout_fields' );
```

Answer (score 0):

WooCommerce sets the address fields order of each country via the get_address_formats() function. For example, Italy has this custom format:

```
'IT' => "{company}\n{name}\n{address_1}\n{address_2}\n{postcode}\n{city}\n{state_upper}\n{country}"
```

Countries, unless specified (like Italy), take this default format:

```
'default' => "{name}\n{company}\n{address_1}\n{address_2}\n{city}\n{state}\n{postcode}\n{country}"
```

As Croatia is not in the custom list, it uses the default format, in fact I can see from your screenshot the address is Name / Company / Address 1 / Address 2 / City / Postcode / Country*

(*) *This is omitted in your case as Shop country is the same as the Customer's country*

Thankfully, the get_address_formats() comes with a filter called 'woocommerce_localisation_address_formats', which means you can override the address format for the desired country, or all countries. In your case, this should work:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_localisation_address_formats', 'bbloomer_change_address_format' );

function bbloomer_change_address_format( $countries ) {
   $countries['default'] = "{company}\n{name}\n{address_1}\n{address_2}\n{city}\n{state}\n{postcode}\n{country}";
   return $countries;
}
```